# jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#cont_name2").autocomplete("<?php echo SITEURL;?>calendar/gl_calendar/gl_auto_uname", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        //mustMatch: true,
        //minChars: 0,
        multiple: true
        //highlight: false,
        //multipleSeparator: ",",
        //selectFirst: false
    });
    $("#cont_name2").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        //$("#meeting_hidden_id").val('');
       // $("#meeting_hidden_email").val('');
        var hidden_id = $("#meeting_hidden_id");
        remove_id_from_hidden(hidden_id);  
        hidden_id.val( (hidden_id.val() ? hidden_id.val() + "," : hidden_id.val()) + data[1]);
        var hidden_email = $("#meeting_hidden_email");
        hidden_email.val( (hidden_email.val() ? hidden_email.val() + "," : hidden_email.val()) + data[2]);
        var meeting_email = $("#meeting_to");
        meeting_email.val( (meeting_email.val() ? meeting_email.val() + "," : meeting_email.val()) + data[2]);

    });

});
```

How to remove the duplicate id using this code?

Comment: What duplicate id are you talking about?

Comment: when we select any value from autocomplete input dropdown, we are storing id in hidden field name #meeting_hidden_id. if we again select the same name from dropdown then id is repeating again & again in same hidden field

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this

```
$("#cont_name2").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        //$("#meeting_hidden_id").val('');
       // $("#meeting_hidden_email").val('');
        var hidden_id = $("#meeting_hidden_id");
        remove_id_from_hidden(hidden_id); 

        if (!hidden_id.val() || !data[1] in hidden_id.val().split(",")){

           hidden_id.val( (hidden_id.val() ? hidden_id.val() + "," : hidden_id.val()) + data[1]);
        }
        var hidden_email = $("#meeting_hidden_email");
        hidden_email.val( (hidden_email.val() ? hidden_email.val() + "," : hidden_email.val()) + data[2]);
        var meeting_email = $("#meeting_to");
        meeting_email.val( (meeting_email.val() ? meeting_email.val() + "," : meeting_email.val()) + data[2]);

    });
```